# Opening DNC, VPF, VMAP in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, vector, vpf

Does anyone know how can I open a VPF or a DNC file in QGIS?
It does not work through normal data layer adding channels.
I can open a shapefile through them just fine.

Documentation says that it should be supported through GDAL, and if I run:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.32.3\bin>ogrinfo --formats
```

I do see that it is supported:

```
OGR_OGDI -vector- (ro): OGDI Vectors (VPF, VMAP, DCW)
```

When I run:
'''
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.32.3\bin>ogrinfo --format OGR_OGDI
'''

I get:

[image]

Unfortunately when I pull in the LHT or the DHT file into QGIS I get an error:
"Invalid Data Source: D:\Development\DNCs\DNC01ED34\DNC01\A0112483\LHT is not a valid or recognized data source."

Do I need to use some plugin for this to be read? Or another import method?
I tried both import options, of looking at the header and the extension, and I get the same problem.

With ogrinfo, if I try to open the format, I get an error:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.32.3\bin>ogrinfo D:\Development\DNCs\DNC01ED34\DNC01\DHT

ogrinfo failed - unable to open 'D:\Development\DNCs\DNC01ED34\DNC01\DHT'.
```

When I do the same thing to a shapefile that I generated from the DNC I get:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.32.3\bin>ogrinfo D:\Development\DNCs\DNC17_ED37_Shape\DNC17_ED37_P.shp

INFO: Open of `D:\Development\DNCs\DNC17_ED37_Shape\DNC17_ED37_P.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: DNC17_ED37_P (Point)
```

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Can you show the results of `ogrinfo gltp:/vrf/D:\Development\DNCs\DNC01ED34\DNC01\A0112483` ?

Comment: do you have the additional drivers files? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5385/working-with-vector-product-format-vpf-apis-etc

Comment: @Mapperz I believe that's an old post before GDAL supported VPF. It does so natively now without a paid 3rd party

Comment: @BradHards When I do that, I get an empty string back:
```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.32.3\bin>ogrinfo gltp:/vrf/D:\Development\DNCs\DNC01ED34\DNC01\A0112483

C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.32.3\bin> 
```

Comment: That makes no sense to me. Maybe this is a windows thing. Possibly try changing the `\` characters to `/`. Also, are these real DNCs (i.e. from NGA or similar)?

Comment: @BradHards Yes, real NGA none CUI DNCs that are publicly available, which I have no problem opening in other software. And obviously we can read them with GDAL through c++ interface, but for some reason QGIS GUI is not liking them. 

And....you are right about it being a windows thing....   
ogrinfo gltp:/vrf/D:/Development/DNCs/DNC01ED34/DNC01/A0112483 did show some results.

So the question is how to do the same in the GUI?

Comment: I have to admit to not being very familiar with QGIS on windows. Can you possibly paste the full path into the dialog?

Comment: @BradHards gltp:/vrf/D:/Development/DNCs/DNC01ED34/DNC01/A0112483 Did seem to work when pasted into the dialog box just for that chart, but the main DHT file still does not work. 
Also, when A0112483  is loaded, after pretty much any large operation... like selecting too many objects, everything crashes.