# Workaround for QGIS unable to load DNC nautical charts (OGDI / VPF format)

Tags: qgis, vpf

I want to load downloaded libraries from the US government's [Digital Nautical Charts](https://dnc.nga.mil/dncp/DNC/background.php) (DNC) into QGIS. They're in VPF format, and QGIS is supposed to be able to load those as OGDI vectors according to the documentation, but there appears to be no way to do so, as thoroughly documented in [Opening DNC, VPF, VMAP in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/469506) and [this QGIS bug report](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/55137). OGDI isn't even one of the options for database types in the "Add Vector Layer" dialogue.

So this is a known bug. But as only a beginner-intermediate GIS user, I'm not sure what kinds of workarounds might be available.

Can anyone suggest one?

Is there some way to open it using GDAL that bypasses the QGIS interface? (I freely admit I have no idea what GDAL actually is.)

Or maybe there's some plugin that could load it, or some other free software that could open it and convert it to a different format that I can read in QGIS?

---

I see that in QGIS v2 there is an option for "OGDI Vectors" in the "Database" section of the "Add vector layer" dialogue (I was using QGIS v3 when I wrote the question). I would test whether it works there, except I can't for the life of me figure out how it's supposed to work (e.g. where do I input the file path to the library?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [GDAL OGDI format](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/ogdi.html) documentation you can use an OGDI "gltp URL":

```
gltp:[//<hostname>]/<driver_name>/<dataset_name>:<layer_name>:<family>
```

The docs give the example:

> ```
> ogrinfo gltp:/vrf/usr4/mpp1/v0eur/vmaplv0/eurnasia 'watrcrsl@hydro(*)_line'
> ```
>
> In the dataset name 'gltp:/vrf/usr4/mpp1/v0eur/vmaplv0/eurnasia' the
> gltp:/vrf part is not really in the filesystem, but has to be added.
> The VPF data was at /usr4/mpp1/v0eur/. **The 'eurnasia' directory should
> be at the same level as the dht. and lat. files.** The 'hydro' reference
> is a subdirectory of 'eurnasia/' where watrcrsl.* is found.

To test, I downloaded the [DNC test dataset](https://dnc.nga.mil/dncp/DNC/dncTestDataSet_Zip.php) from the [NGA DNC page](https://dnc.nga.mil/dncp/DNC/background.php) and extracted the zipfile to `/tmp/DNC_Test_Data` and got `ogrinfo` to read one of the charts (e.g. A1708280 which is one of the data folders located at the same directory level as the DHT and LAT files):

[image]

```
ogrinfo -so -al gltp:/vrf/tmp/DNC_Test_Data/DNC17/A1708280
INFO: Open of `gltp:/vrf/tmp/DNC_Test_Data/DNC17/A1708280'
      using driver `OGR_OGDI' successful.

Layer name: buildnga@cul(*)_area
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (-76.027267, 36.864147) - (-76.026268, 36.865425)
Layer SRS WKT:
<snip...>
```

I could then paste that gltp URL into the "Datasource Manager -> Vector" or "add Vector Layer..." dialog to  add one or more of the layers from that chart to QGIS:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note 1. I haven't tested on Windows, I'm using a Linux PC so the filesystem will be different to Windows. If that is the OS you run, you could try something like `gltp:/vrf/C:/Temp/DNC_Test_Data/DNC17/A1708280` as noted in the comments of [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/469506/2856).

Note 2. I tried adding all the layer from that chart to QGIS and it crashed (also noted  in the comments of the [same thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/469506/2856)), but I had no issue with just a few.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much! This does allow me to load the layers. QGIS becomes very unstable - for example, it crashes when loading multiple layers at once, and also when zooming or panning the map canvas when more than one layer is displayed, and it was impossible to re-open a saved QGIS project with several of the layers in it (!!). But I can load them one at a time and re-export them as shapefiles, which is good enough for my use case.

Comment: For noobs like me who have trouble following the above, do this:
1. In Explorer, copy the path to the data folder that's in the same folder as the file called "DHT" (not the folder *containing* "DHT")
2. Add gltp:/vrf/ to the beginning of the file path, before the C:/
3. Change all the backslashes in the path to forward slashes
4. Paste the resulting path (e.g. gltp:/vrf/C:/Temp/DNC_Test_Data/DNC17/A1708280 ) directly into the "Vector Dataset(s)" field in "Add Vector Layer", then click "Add".

Make sure to finished editing the path before pasting it in, or QGIS will crash.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the GDAL doc notes chart data folder is at same folder level as DHT and LAT files. I've edited above to make that clearer.